# how to remove space from variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to know how to remove space from a variable or item in ansible.

I have a file with aline like this:

```
abc de fg
```

I do:

```yaml
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    output: "{{ item }}"
  with_lines: /path/to/file
```

From example I get the following debug output:

> ok: [localhost] => (item=abc de fg) => {"ansible_facts": {"servicename": "abc de fg"}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "abc de fg"}

I'd like to change it to:

> ok: [localhost] => (item=abcdefg) => {"ansible_facts": {"servicename": "abcdefg"}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "abcdefg"}`.

I know I can add a task like:

```yaml
- command: sed -i 's/ //g' file
```

Before the task but I would like to know if there is another way.

Best regards.

Comment: checkout about `replace` filter in ansible.

Comment: i.e. `ansible localhost -m debug -e "my_var='abc de fg'" -a "msg={{ my_var | replace(' ', '') }}"`

Comment: Another hack would be to do `"{{ 'abc de fg' | split | join }}"`, which split on space and rejoin all elements of the list.
`

Comment: Thank you all,
 the regex_replace filter did the work